# Props en React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, props

Estoy empezando a usar Props en React, pero no entiendo su uso. Empece con algo sencillo que es mostrar un mensaje por consola. En un componente esta el boton y en el otro componente el mensaje, pero no me llega nada.

Componente 1

```javascript
    //Recibo la funcion "tocar" por props que viene desde el segundo componente

    export const PrimerComponente = ({tocar}) => {

        return (

            <>
            
            <h2>Soy el primer Componente</h2>
            <button onClick={tocar}>Enviar</button>
            </>
        )
      }
```

Segundo Componente

```javascript
    const SegundoComponente = () => {

        const tocar = () =>{
            console.log("Me presionaste");

        }

        return (
            <>
            <h2>Soy el segundo Componente</h2>
            
            <PrimerComponente
            tocar={tocar}
            />

            </>
        )
    }

    export default SegundoComponente
```

Mi otra pregunta aprovechando el post. ¿Como se quien es el componente padre e hijo? Existe alguna convención para identificarlos o eso depende plenamente de quien pase componentes a quien?

¿Se pueden pasar parámetros o funciones de un componente a otro bidireccionalmente?, es decir que ambos se envíen parámetros uno al otro en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Técnicamente el código debería funcionar, confirma si se esta importando `PrimerComponente` en `SegundoComponente`, puede que por esa razón no "te llegue nada".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Conceptualmente, los componentes son como las funciones de JavaScript.
> Aceptan entradas arbitrarias (llamadas “props”) y devuelven a React
> elementos que describen lo que debe aparecer en la pantalla.

Fuente: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

En otras palabras, los props son las propiedades que le envías a tus componentes en forma de atributos html con el fin de mostrar información en la pantalla del usuario.

La idea de los componente es tener un pedacito de tu web véase un calendario, formulario, modal, navbar o tabla que se escriba su código una sola vez, y este a su vez pueda usarse en diferentes partes de tu web.

Muchas veces tendrás la necesidad de usar el mismo componente pero que muestre datos diferentes de acuerdo a lo que necesites.

Aquí es cuando entran los props, digamos que tenemos el componente Usuario, dicho componente muestra en pantalla un  con el nombre del usuario en la pantalla.

El componente Usuario:

```
export const Usuario = (props) => {

        return (

            <>
            
            <h2>{props.nombre}</h2>
            </>
        )
      }
```

Dentro de app.js declaro al componente Usuario pero le paso diferentes props:

Obtengo:

```
ivan
Ralex
```

Acceder especificamente a un prop con las llaves esta bien, pero por lo general querrar recibir todos los props dentro de tu componente y si a du

Enviando varios props:

```
<PrimerComponente nombre="ivan" edad="20"/>
```

Accedes a los props con la notación del punto de javascript:

```
export const PrimerComponente = (props) => {

    return (

        <>
        
        <h2>{props.nombre}</h2>
        <h2>{props.edad}</h2>
        </>
    )
```

Obtendras:

```
Ivan
20
```

Para react todo es un componte, la idea de react es crear un jerarquía de componente donde los datos se envíen del padre a o a los hijos, [La documentación de react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) tiene una guía explicando esto, sin embargo a mi no me quedo claro por eso te recomiendo [te recomiendo ver este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyullfdLGoE&t=995s)